# Serving Meteor on main domain and Apache on subdomain independently

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, port, ipv6, meteor

I'm running a Meteor server on my Ubuntu server. But problems arise when I try to have Apache serving a subdomain on the same server.

main.domain.com -> Meteor

sub.domain.com -> Apache

Meteor is running on port 80. I have previously tried to have Meteor run on port 3000 and served in reverse proxy with Nginx, but Meteor started to behave badly (tcp/websockets issues) and I spent too many evenings and nights to persist for my own sake.

So I reverted my setup to have Meteor being the main server (app works fine), and then install Apache the serve my subdomain. The problem is I cannot have Apache serve on port 80 too since it seems to overrun my Meteor server.

From experience, I try to stay away from reverse-proxying Meteor, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to get Apache to dedicate itself to my subdomain and without overwhelming "everything port 80" on my server.

How can I have both services behave with each other in this kind of setup?

---

Update:

Following EasyEcho suggestion, I turned to using 2 different ip addresses.

Let it be known, I'm using a "Next Generation" Cloud server on Rackspace (running the latest Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with latest grub2/updated kernel.

Rackspace does not allow additional IPs on their Cloud Servers ([source](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/requesting-additional-ipv4-addresses))...

> The next generation Cloud Servers platform powered by OpenStack does
>   not yet support additional IP addresses.

... but you get 1 IPv4 and 1 IPv6 when creating a server. So why not hop into the IPv6 bandwagon? Easier said than done.

So here is my "new problem": After mapping my subdomain to the IPv6 address (AAAA in DNS) and configuring Apache to listen to the IPv6 address, I get this following behavior:

From my server remote desktop (using freeNX), in Firefox

- http:// [my:ip:v6:address] -> Apache (WIN)
- http:// sub.domain.com -> Apache (WIN)
- http:// my.ip.v4.address -> Meteor (WIN)
- http:// main.domain.com -> Apache (FAIL)

From my workstation (Win7 x64), also in Firefox

- http:// [my:ip:v6:address] -> The connection has timed out (FAIL)
- http:// sub.domain.com -> Server not found (FAIL)
- http:// my.ip.v4.address -> Meteor (WIN)
- http:// main.domain.com -> Meteor (WIN)

Here is my Apache configuration:

**/etc/apache2/ports.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost [my:ip:v6:address]:80
Listen [my:ip:v6:address]:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default**

```
<VirtualHost [my:ip:v6:address]:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName sub.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Can this be fixed to work as "advertised"?

Comment: What is returned from "dig main.domain.com" on the remote ubuntu machine?

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! Just did the dig. Here are the results: http://pastebin.com/GPAdy2d2

Comment: Also, I found a very interesting thread here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/159 - there might be a --binding=ip param in a future update of Meteor. Does not solve the problem in the "here and now", but nice to know I'm not alone with these kind of issues.

Answer (score 1):

If possible assign multiple IPs to the machine and set Meteor to bind to 80 on one of the ips and Apache to bind to port 80 on the other.  See [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html) and [Meteor Demo](http://meteorserver.org/demo/) which seems to cover what you are looking for.

---

Update:

Well that is lots of new info...

You likely can't connect to the IPv6 ip/host from your workstation because you are on IPv4.

Comment: Excellent point! But I'm trying to avoid the multiple IPs solution... Also, this is the Meteor server I'm talking about: http://www.meteor.com/main

Is there any other workaround beside going with multiple IPs?

Comment: Damn that is confusing.  It isn't possible to bind multiple applications to the same port/ip combination. Whichever application grabs the port first based on start order will be the winner.  Apache can also function as a proxy server as well so that could be an option to try.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Really appreciated. I'll try to proxy with Apache, but with the kind of results I got from Nginx, I'm a little skeptical... I'll post my result back here.

Comment: I have tried with 2 IP adresses, but got very strange results (see my update).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you shouldn't need multiple IP addresses to do this.

Listen on 0.0.0.0:80 with something lightweight like NginX or HAProxy (scaling won't be a problem), and then reverse proxy the traffic through to the relevant layer underneath, running on a separate ports (listen on localhost, not 0.0.0.0).

So, request comes in for `apache.your_domain.com`, and HAProxy internally routes the traffic through to Apache running on another port.

Request comes in for `meteor.your_domain.com`, and HAProxy internally routes the traffic through to Node.js...